# Make apt-get install an older version

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to downgrade mysql from 5.1 to 5.0.

After running `apt-get remove mysql-server-5.1` I am attempting to run `apt-get install mysql-server-5.0`.

It says: `Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.1' instead of 'mysql-server-5.0'`

How do I force it not to do that and to use 5.0 as desired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL 5.0 is not available for anything after Ubuntu 8.04 (hardy).  8.04 Server Edition is still supported for a couple of years, so that might be an option for you.

Here are the official packages by release for 5.0:

```
$ rmadison mysql-server-5.0
mysql-server-5.0 | 5.0.21-3ubuntu1 |        dapper | amd64, i386, powerpc
mysql-server-5.0 | 5.0.22-0ubuntu6.06.15 | dapper-security | amd64, i386, powerpc
mysql-server-5.0 | 5.0.22-0ubuntu6.06.15 | dapper-updates | amd64, i386, powerpc
mysql-server-5.0 | 5.0.51a-3ubuntu5 |         hardy | amd64, i386
mysql-server-5.0 | 5.0.51a-3ubuntu5.8 | hardy-security | amd64, i386
mysql-server-5.0 | 5.0.51a-3ubuntu5.8 | hardy-updates | amd64, i386
mysql-server-5.0 | 5.1.30really5.0.83-0ubuntu3 | karmic/universe | amd64, i386
```

Comment: I'm developing on Ubuntu 10.10, but the live server which the development environment needs to mirror to eliminate problems is running on MySQL 5.0.x. I can't change either OS.

Comment: I would suggest creating a virtual machine that mirrors the production environment.  You could also start up an instance of Ubuntu 8.04 on Amazon EC2 for your development.